# 68k Assembly: Does the CPU does store the status register on interrupt?

Tags: interrupt, 68000, easy68k

I have not been able to find any information as to whether the MC68000 preserves its status register / CCR during external interrupts.  I imagine it would be an issue if the CPU were to interrupt immediately before a conditional branch, and the interrupt modifies the CCR.  Right now my interrupt code looks like this:

```
            ORG     $110000   ; Location of IPL6 vector
IPL6        MOVE.W  SR, -(SP) ; Is this line necessary?
            MOVE.L  D0, -(SP)
            ; Perform interrupt tasks here
            MOVE.L  (SP)+, D0
            MOVE.W  (SP)+, SR ; Is this line necessary?
            RTE               ; Return
```

I'm wondering if the indicated lines that push/pop the SR from the stack are required, or if the CPU automatically saves and restores the SR during interrupts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the CPU does store the status register on interrupt. Logically this is needed or otherwise issues like you mentioned would happen.

On page 6-84 of [MOTOROLA
 M68000 FAMILY
 Programmer’s Reference Manual](https://www.google.lt/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nxp.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwju8bPmyZ_SAhUsJJoKHXlVCr4QFggYMAA&usg=AFQjCNGm1i7IrWM57G4pe49IlajPrykzbw&sig2=Hnf2SvkMifX_x9kFtruU2g) the `RTE` command shows that it restores `SR` among other registers so it has to have been stored previously.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually stated in a bit of an unlucky way because you don't state *by whom* (CPU or code):

**Yes**, the CCR *needs* to be preserved during interrupts (for obvious reasons that you have stated).

But **no**, it doesn't need to be *explicitly* preserved by the programmer (like it's unnecessarily done in your example), because the CPU does it automatically when it serves an interrupt.

Comment: Fair enough, I tweaked the title a little.